# Magento - cms/page collection - apply filter to return only pages which are unique to a given store id (ie not also assigned to other stores)

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I can use:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($store_id);
```

to retrieve a collection of CMS pages filtered by Store Id.

But how do I get it to remove ones which are also assigned to other stores?

ie: I do not want it to return items which have 'All Store Views' as the Store View. (Or any other additional store id assigned to that CMS page.) It has to only return pages unique to that one store.

I am extending the Aitoc permissions module, so that Store Admins cant view or edit CMS pages and static blocks which might impact other stores. This involves filtering those items from the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fusing some elements of the solutions proposed by Alan and Vitaly with my own cumbersome understanding, I achieved what I needed with the following code.

*To put into context, I was extending the Aitoc permissions module, so that Store Admins cant view or edit CMS pages and static blocks which might impact other stores. This involved filtering those items from the grid.*

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
$collection->addStoreFilter(Mage::helper('aitpermissions')->getStoreIds());
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$page_ids = array();
foreach($collection as $key=>$item) {
    $page_id = $item->getId();
    $results = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM cms_page_store 
                                WHERE page_id = ".$page_id.";");
    $count = 0;
    $arr_stores = array();
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $arr_stores[] = $row['store_id'];
        $count++;
    }

    //We dont want to show the item if any of the following are true:
       //The store id = 0 (Means its assigned to All Stores)
       //There is more than one store assigned to this CMS page         
    if( in_array('0',$arr_stores) || $count>1) {
            //This removes results from the grid (but oddly not the paging)
        $collection->removeItemByKey($key); 
    }
    else {
        //build an array which we will use to remove results from the paging
        $page_ids[] = $page_id; 
    }
}

//This removes results from paging (but not the grid)
$collection->addFieldToFilter('page_id',array('in'=>$page_ids));
```

I'm not sure why I needed to use two different methods to filter from the paging and the grid.
 The site uses magento 1.5 so perhaps there is an issue related to that.

Either way, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

There's no native collection method to do this, so you'll need to

1. Query the `cms_page_store` table for pages unique to a given store
2. Use the results from above in your filter

I didn't fully test the following, but it **should** work (and if it doesn't, it'll give you a good start on your own query)

```
$page     = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
$resource = $page->getResource();
$read     = $resource->getReadConnection();

#$select   = $read->query('SELECT page_id FROM ' . $resource->getTable('cms/page_store') . ' GROUP BY store_id');

//set total count to look for.  1 means the page only appears once.
$total_stores_count_to_look_for = '1';

//get the table name.  Need to pass through getTable to ensure any prefix used is added
$table_name                     = $resource->getTable('cms/page_store');

//aggregate count select from the cmd_page_store database
//greater than 0 ensures the "all stores" pages aren't selected
$select = $read->query('SELECT page_id as total
FROM '.$table_name.' 
WHERE store_id > 0 
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING count(page_id) = ?',array($total_stores_count_to_look_for));

//fetch all the rows, which will be page ids
$ids   = $select->fetchAll(); 

//query for pages using IDs from above
$pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('page_id',array('in'=>$ids));

foreach($pages as $page)
{
    var_dump($page->getData());
}
```

If you have thousands and thousands of CMS pages it may be worth it to alter the `cms/page` collection's `select` to join in aggregate table data. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader, as those sorts of joins can get tricky.

Comment: What @Vitaly Muminov says below.

Comment: Thanks - This is an incredibly insightful answer all the same.

Answer (score 4):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array('cps' => $collection->getTable('cms/page_store')),
        'cps.page_id = main_table.page_id AND cps.store_id != 0',
        array('store_id')
    )
    ->columns(array('stores_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(cps.store_id)')))
    ->group('main_table.page_id')
    ->having('stores_count = ?', 1)
    ->having('cps.store_id = ?', $storeId)
;
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution but it's producing the error:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stores_count' in 'having clause' when I try it. Which seems odd as it looks like it is declared in the array above it.

Comment: oops, i've made a mistake. Answer is now containing right query.

Comment: Thanks for checking - still getting 'Unknown column 'stores_count' in 'having clause'.
I'm doing it on Magento 1.5 - so it could be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to add field store_id to pages collection via join, and use collection method addFieldToFilter().

```
$pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();

$pages->getSelect()->joinInner(
     array('cms_page_store' => 'cms_page_store'),
     'main_table.page_id = cms_page_store.page_id',
     array()
);

$pages->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['in' => [1, 2]]);
```